# How to assign to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, assign

Sorry I have searched for this, and it seems simple but I can't figure it out.  I am trying to assign values to a list in my dict:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.test =  { "color": ["", "", "", ""],
                          "incandescence": ["", "", "", ""] }

    def setTest(self):
        key = "color"
        print "KEY is", key
        self.test[key][0] = "TEST"

        print self.test

    def clearDict(self):  
        for key in self.test:
            self.test[key] = ""      

x = Test()
x.clearDict()
x.setTest()
```

## Error: line 1: TypeError: file  line 10: 'str' object does not support item assignment #

Why can't I assign a string to the 0th element?  How is this not the same as:

```
test = ["", "", ""]

test[0] = "test"

print test
```

Answer: ['test', '', '']

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `clearDict`

```
def clearDict(self):  
    for key in self.test:
        self.test[key] = ""
```

You are setting the dictionary element to be a blank string. I think you want something like:

```
    def clearDict(self):  
    for key in self.test:
        for l in self.test[key]:
            self.test[key][l] = ""
```

Comment: Thank you.  Everyone pretty much found the issue, which was a stupid one.  Ugh..  gave the credit to the first person I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well because after creating `x` you call `clearDict` on it which changes `x.test` to `{"color": '', "incandescence": ''}`

So when calling `setTest` afterwards you are trying to set the first element of the empty string values in your dictionary to `"TEST"`, which fails because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your clearDict method... you are setting the value of self.test[key] to a string

```
self.test[key] = ""
```

Once you do that, you cannot set a section of a string with an index... if you change your method to create a new list, you will have better luck.

```
self.test[key] = []
```

---

**Note**

As an aside, instead of using the [0] notation to set the 0th element, you could have initialized like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.test = { "color": [], "incandescence": [] }
```

then simply appended to your list to add items

```
def set_test(self):
    self.test["color"].append("TEST")
```

to achieve the same result without having to know exactly how many elements are in the list.